# php static variable is not getting set

Tags: php

I have a situation where i need to maintain a static variable globally where it value can be change by diferent php files.

I have below class,

```
<?php
class FlagMe {
    public static $flag;

    public static function setFlag($flag) {
        self::$flag = $flag;
    }

    public static function getFlag() {

        return self::$flag;
    }
}
?>
```

And I am setting a value from a diferent php file like below,

```
FlagMe::setFlag("SomeValue");
```

But suppose after a post request code flow in same php script (controller class) with a page refresh, and when I am try to access that static variable it gives me instead of giveing the set value "SomeValue" previously.

```
$temVar = FlagMe::getFlag(); // gives null
```

What am I missing here please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the page is refreshed, a new execution of the script occurs. Object instances/class variables are not saved between different executions.

If you wish to save a variable, store it in a [session](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or a [cookie](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). Then, on every execution, check for the session and set the variable accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, which means a user's data isn't saved between page requests.

If you want to save variables over multiple pages you should use sessions or cookies.

Comment: It's not related to HTTP being stateless. It's related to the fact that PHP has one process per request. In a Java web app, for example, the same process is used for all the requests, and this code would work.

Answer (score 3):

Two requests mean two executions of the script, and two distinct memory spaces. At the end of the first request, the first script ends, and all the changes it made in memory are forgotten. The second script starts from scratch, with all the variables having their default value.

If the variable is linked to the current user, you should store it in the session. Else, you should store it in a file or database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempVar = FlagMe::setFlag("SomeValue");
```

is wrong because `setFlag` function doesn't return any value.
You have to use only `FlagMe::setFlag("SomeValue");`.

Try to add echo `"setFlag value is ".$flag` to `setFlag` to see what's going with flag.

Anyway I think your problem is that after refreshing data changes. You have to use Sessions to store information between the pages.