# Static variable not being set?

Tags: php, variables, static, set

I searched, and found this question, which helped me:
[php static variable is not getting set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049379/php-static-variable-is-not-getting-set)

It did, however, not solve my entire problem.

Code:

```
Class DummyClass {
    public static $result;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_setResultCode('testing');
    }

    public function getResultCode() {
        return self::$result['code'];
    }

    private function _setResultCode($val) {
        echo 'Im gonna set it to: ' . $val . '<br />';
        self::$result['code'] = $val;
        echo 'I just set it to: ' . $this->getResultCode;
        die();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Im gonna set it to: testing
I just set it to:
```

What's going on here? How is this even possible?

---

**EDIT:** The problem was i missed the parentheses when calling getResultCode(). HOWEVER, i have another issue now. I can't seem to get the resultCode out of the class (later on in another instance of DummyClass).

Here is my relevant coded (No more example code because i seemed to mess that up):

```
Class lightweightContactFormPlugin {

// Set up/Init static $result variable
public static $result;

function __construct() {
    //echo 'I just inited<br/><pre>';
    //var_dump($this->getResultCode());
    //echo '</pre><br/>';
}

public function run() {

    // Set default value for resultCode
    $this->_setResultCode('no_identifier');

    // Check if form was posted
    if(isset($_POST['cfidentifier'])) {
        $fields = $this->_get_fields_to_send();
        $valid = $this->_validate_fields($fields);

        // Only continue if validatation was successful
        if($valid == true) {
            // Store mail result in $mail
            $mail = $this->_send_mail($fields);

            // Yay, success!
            if($mail) {
                $this->_setResultCode('sent_successfully');
                return;
            } else {
                // Couldn't send mail, bu-hu!
                $this->_setResultCode('not_sent');
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_setResultCode('validation_fail');
        return;
    }
}


    // Get and Set methods
public function getResultCode() {
    return isset(self::$result['code']) ? self::$result['code'] : '';
}

private function _setResultCode($val) {
    self::$result['code'] = $val;
}
}
```

Left some irrelevant methods out. None of the other methods set or get the resultCode, it shouldn't matter.

Any ideas why i can't access $result['code'] in another instance of the object (further down the page)?

I do this when i access it:

```
    $plugin = new lightweightContactFormPlugin();
    $cfstat = $plugin->getResultCode();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($fstat);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Result is:

```
NULL
```

The strange thing is, if i uncomment the code in __construct(), the CORRECT value does get printed out! But if i try to access it from getResultCode() after, it returns NULL again. What is going on?

Comment: yourt getResultCode function does not return anything.

Comment: That's a mistake in the code, i just noticed. That's not the problem, i have set it to return `self::$result['code']` as it should be. I fixed the code in the question now.

Comment: You're dumping `$fstat` but are writing the return value of `getResultCode` into a variable called `$cfstat`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that should print out the resultCode stored in $fstat, right? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'I just set it to: ' . $this->getResultCode;
```

I think you're missing a few parenthesis here.

Comment: @qwerty would you validate the answer, maybe =) ?

Comment: @qwerty Ok, didn't know that. I haven't asked many questions :p

Comment: Will you please take a look at my edit? Still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have no return within `getResultCode()`

Comment: That's a mistype, i just edited the question. blue112 has the answer.

Comment: Will you please take a look at my edit? Still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

use return like this

```
public function getResultCode() {
    return self::$result['code'];
}
```

and use `$this->getResultCode();`

**EDIT**

the only problem i can see is you have just written `return;` , because of that it return `NULL`, change it to

```
return $this->getResultCode();
```

Comment: That's a mistype, i just edited the question. blue112 has the answer.

Comment: Will you please take a look at my edit? Still having problems.

Comment: You're right, i just realised since run() is returning null, $plugin is null when creating an instance of the plugin. I just removed the return alltogether, and moved the `$this->_setResultCode('validation_fail')` into an else() under the `if($valid == true)`. Now it works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call getResultCode() as a method.

```
    echo 'I just set it to: ' . $this->getResultCode();
```

Comment: Will you please take a look at my edit? Still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

A. your code is wrong ... there is nothing like `__constructor` in PHP it should be

```
     function __construct() {
```

B. Your code should also return the following since `getResultCode` was not set

```
    Notice: Undefined property: DummyClass::$getResultCode
```

You should be calling

```
    echo 'I just set it to: ' . $this->getResultCode();
```

Your Final Code :

```
class DummyClass {
    public static $result;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_setResultCode('testing');
    }

    public function getResultCode() {
        return self::$result['code'];
    }

    private function _setResultCode($val) {
        echo 'Im gonna set it to: ' . $val . '<br />';
        self::$result['code'] = $val;
        echo 'I just set it to: ' . $this->getResultCode();
        die();
    }
}

new DummyClass();
```

Output

```
Im gonna set it to: testing
I just set it to: testing
```

Comment: Point A was a mistype. I didn't copy the code right off my class, i wrote a dummy class and just copied the getResultCode() and _setResultCode() methods (with little altering). Point B is valid though, i forgot the parentheses.

Comment: Will you please take a look at my edit? Still having problems.

Comment: @qwerty from your code you are calling `$plugin->run();` so no ouput was returned ...... see : http://codepad.viper-7.com/4VuifJ

Comment: blue112 answered the initial question before you, and Yogesh Suthar answered my second question before you. Sorry, gotta be fast!